# How can I configure `Strip trailing spaces on Save` by file type in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, markdown

Aggressive auto-stripping of trailing spaces is a nice feature to have on most files, except for Markdown.

AFAIK, the only way to add a newline (the equivalent to a `<br>`, not a `<p>`) in Markdown is to [end a line with two or more spaces](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p).

In IntelliJ I can configure this under `Editor > General`, in the `Other` section, by setting `Strip trailing spaces on Save` to `None` - but I can't find a way to set this to `None` only for `*.md` files and to `Modified Lines` / `All` for `*.scala` or `*.java` files, for example.

I'm using IntelliJ Community Edition 2016.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2 and earlier, this is not possible. There is an [open feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-69051) for this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.editorconfig` file on your root directory of the project.

```
root = true

[*]
charset = utf-8
end_of_line = lf
indent_size = 2
indent_style = space
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
max_line_length = 0
tab_width = 2

[{*.ats,*.cts,*.mts,*.ts}]
indent_size = 2
tab_width = 2

[*.md]
trim_trailing_whitespace=false
```

I have set `trim_trailing_whitespace=true` for all files and set false on `*.md` files. You can add more file types as follows.

```
[{*.md, *.txt}]
trim_trailing_whitespace=false
```